# ruby socket programming using credentials

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpsocket

HI folks,

I'm trying to establish connection to a remote server using ruby socket connection TcpSocket.

I started with TcpSocket.new(port,host)

Now, How do I pass the credentials to it.

The remote server needs credentials to allow me to connect.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is the remote server using SSL? What credentials are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must say with port and layer 7 protocol you are trying to use. A TCP socket itself don't n need any authentication. Probably you are trying to establish a layer 7 protocol connection (ftp, http, pop3) and then you will need a credential. If you specifiy in which port you are trying to connect maybe would be easier to help you